# How do I clear / reset a Kendo DropDownList with only javascript?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a Kendo DropDownList (name=Function) that contains 3 options. When one option is selected, it triggers an ajax call to get data to populate a different DropDownList (name=Parents). This works as-expected. However, if the user then changes the original DropDownList "Function" back to a different selection, I need to clear/reset (remove all options) and disable the "Parents" DropDownList.

```
function LoadKendoDropdownContents(dropdownBoxId, data) {
  var dropdownBox = $("#" + dropdownBoxId).data("kendoDropDownList");

  if (data === "" || data === null || $.isEmptyObject(data)) {
    var dataSource = [];
  }
  else {    
    var dataSource = data;
  }

  dropdownBox.setDataSource(dataSource);
}
```

It's really the "var dataSource = []" that is giving me problems. It's like the "Parents" DropDownList isn't refreshing/rebinding when that is applied. All of the options except the one that was selected get removed, but how do I remove the one that was previously selected? I want it to be "empty" again.

Thank you.

***---- Solution I used ----***

```
function LoadKendoDropdownContents(dropdownBoxId, data) {
  var dropdownBox = $("#" + dropdownBoxId).data("kendoDropDownList");

  if (data === "" || data === null || $.isEmptyObject(data)) {
    var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
      data: []
    });

    dropdownBox.text(" --- ");
    dropdownBox.value(-1);
  }
  else {
    var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
      data: data
    });

    dropdownBox.text("[Select]");
    dropdownBox.value(-1);
  }

  dropdownBox.setDataSource(dataSource);
}
```

Comment: I also found out that the dropdownBox.value(-1) doesn't work. It appears impossible to "unselect" all values once one has been selected.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It might be easier to use the [cascading dropdown](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/dropdownlist/cascadingdropdownlist.html) feature.

When you change the dataSource, it removes the dropdown items, but you also need to clear the selected text and disable the box, by calling:

```
dropdownBox.setDataSource(dataSource);
dropdownBox.text('');
dropdownBox.enable(false);
```

Comment: It was the resetting of the text that I missed. I guess I assumed that resetting the datasource would reset everything, but that appears to be incorrect. In my code I also reset the dropdownBox.value() as it appeared to retain that information as well. Thank you for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

If you have defined a data source for both the parent and child drop down then you could use the cascadeFrom('parent') method in the child and set a value that you can identify as null or clear.

Comment: I guess it's setting that data source 'as null or clear' that is throwing me off? Shouldn't I be able to set a data source like that without utilizing the cascade event?